# Upvoting answers on opinion-based questions?

Tags: discussion

**TL;DR** - Should answers to opinion-based questions be upvoted?

---

Afternoon,

I am a little concerned with the number of off-topic questions that slip through currently, obviously, this is a growing exchange so it's inevitable these numbers will rise; however what I am more concerned about is the following.

If a question is seeking product recommendation or is opinion based, should answers really be upvoted? (I've had this happen to myself I am not blaming people) but surely upvoting those answers is just going to encourage the user that this is acceptable behaviour, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure what we can do about it if the answers are upvoted though. In general, we should not engage (or answer) off-topic questions.

Comment: I guess my thought would be downvote them? However the more I think about it that is not fair on the user because they might've written a good answer. Yeah, it's a bit of a... No-win situation a little I guess.

Comment: Downvoting a good answer to a less than optimal question seems harsh. We *want* good answers.

Comment: Yeah precisely @schroeder that's what I was thinking it wouldn't be fair on the user.

Comment: I agree with @schroeder, but I should also point out that sometimes (rarely) an offtopic question is saved by a really good answer.